# After adding Parse sdk in existing project, GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h file not found in Xcode 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, parse-platform, google-maps-sdk-ios

Google SDK used in my existing project. After that I want to implement Parse Cloud in my application. Then I just follow this below link:
[enter link description here](https://www.parse.com/docs/)

But I found below problem after add all libraries in my project & build the project

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found

Please give me some suggestion ....

Comment: are you using Google Maps in your application??, this error has nothing to do with Parse.com iOS library as per my experience with parse.com

Comment: Yes. I am using Google maps. I am also create a test application using Parse SDK & it's working fine. When I try to add Parse SDK in my Project then this type of issue arise.

Comment: did u add google frame work to your project??

Comment: Yes. My existing project was working perfect with Google SDK before add Parse SDK.

Comment: that error is clearly due to google maps sdk, check if your using new google maps framework can you redownload it again and link it ,if not update google framework.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with GoogleMaps and another framework. You may try going into Build Settings > Framework Search Paths and rearranging the order of the frameworks so that Parse is loaded before GoogleMaps.